# JavaScript inserted DOM elements destroy themselves

Tags: javascript

So you can see the text in a milisecond when the button has been clicked and then the nodes destroy themselfs.Why?

```
function comprobarCampos() {
    for (var i = 0; i < campos.length; i++) {
        if (campos[i].value == "") {
            result.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Campo " + campos[i].id +
                        " esta vacio!"));
        }
        else {
            result.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Campo " + campos[i].id +
                        " tiene el valor: "+campos[i].value));
        }
        console.log(i);
    }
}

document.getElementById("reg").addEventListener("click", function () 
{ 
    comprobarCampos() 
}, false);
```

Comment: Without seeing the HTML, I'd say the button is within a form, and clicking it will submit the form.

Comment: write an answer so i can mark it as the solution haha

Comment: I can't, considering the given information, that would be pure speculation ; ).

Comment: Its the right one ... such a dum error

Comment: result is a div in wich i create the text nodes, but teemu was rigth,the button was in a form tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because when you add a new element, it is then immediately added to the array "campos", thus it is the next to be "analyzed" and changed